# Obtener array de valores a partir de la substracción iterativa de los valores subsiguientes dentro del array

Tags: python-3.x

Dispongo de un array del tipo:

```
import numpy as np

mi_array = np.array([1,2,3])
```

Ahora, dado un valor de inicio determinado, por ejemplo 100, me gustaría calcular el array que se forma al ir restando el valor subsiguiente al resultado de la substracción previa. Es decir, me gustaría obtener el resultado de:

100 - 1, 99 - 2, 97 - 3

Es decir, el array `[99, 97, 94]`

He intentado lo siguiente.

```
import numpy as np

a= np.array([1,2,3])


def resta_iterativa(value):
    result = []
    for i in a:
        resta = value - i
        result.append(resta)
        return result
        
print(resta_iterativa(100))
```

El objetivo es conseguir un código más eficiente, y que funcione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que planteas es equivalente a lo siguiente:

- Primer elemento del resultado: 100 - 1
- Segundo elemento del resultado: 100 - (1+2)
- Tercer elemento del resultado: 100 - (1+2+3)
- ...

Por lo tanto puedes hacer uso de `np.cumsum()` que te devuelve la suma acumulada de un array (es decir, te devuelve uno nuevo en el que cada elemento es igual a la suma acumulada de todos los anteriores, lo que en tu caso será el array [1, 1+2, 1+2+3]), y simplemente restarle a 100 ese resultado:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
result = 100 - np.cumsum(a)
print(result)
```

Y se obtiene lo que buscabas:

```
[99 97 94]
```

### Bonus

¿Por qué no funcionaba tu código? Hay dos razones fundamentales:

1. Tienes el `return` metido dentro del bucle, por lo que tras la primera iteración ya retornas `result`, que en ese momento tiene un solo elemento `[99]`. El `return result` debería estar fuera del bucle
2. Aún si mueves el return fuera, el resultado que obtienes no es el que quieres. Obtendrás `[99, 98, 97]` debido a que `value` siempre es 100, pero tú querías que fuese descendiendo también. Te faltaba para eso hacer `value = value - i`

Es decir:

```
def resta_iterativa(value):
    result = []
    for i in a:
        resta = value - i
        value = value - i
        result.append(resta)
    return result
```

Esto ya funcionará como quieres, pero es mucho más ineficiente que la solución planteada más arriba usando `cumsum()`.

Comment: Desconocía **cumsum()**, excelente respuesta.